# Service reference is NULL when injecting it into a class

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have the following class:

```
public class BooleanState
{
    [Inject] private IStringLocalizer<App> localizer { get; set; }

    public bool Value { get; set; }
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }

    public BooleanState(bool value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
        this.DisplayText = value == true
            ? localizer["Yes"]
            : localizer["No"];
    }

    public BooleanState(bool value, string displayText) 
    {
        this.Value = value;
        this.DisplayText = displayText;
    }

    public static readonly IReadOnlyList<BooleanState> List = new BooleanState[] {
        new(true),
        new(false)
    };
}
```

However, the `localizer` instance is `NULL` when I do `BooleanState.List` in a razor page. How can I get to inject the service correctly in the class?

Comment: Have you registered the concrete type, relationship to `IStringLocalizer`? Also, I think that your class needs to derive from `BlazorComponent` to use the syntax given above otherwise it will be using ASP.NET DI and therefore must be used in the constructor.

Comment: Please provide the code where the localization service is registered (Startup).

Comment: `IStringLocalizer` is from ASP.NET and gets injected automatically. I'm assuming when calling `services.AddLocalization(...)`.

Comment: The Inject Attribute is for Razor files. To inject into a class, use the constructor. The class that uses the injection also has to be setup for DI.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by doing it this way:

```
public interface IBooleanStateSercive
{
    IReadOnlyList<BooleanState> List();
}

public class BooleanStateService : IBooleanStateSercive
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<App> localizer;

    public BooleanStateService(IStringLocalizer<App> localizer)
    {
        this.localizer = localizer;
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<BooleanState> List() => new BooleanState[] {
        new(true, localizer["Yes"]),
        new(false, localizer["No"])
    };
}

public class BooleanState
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }

    public BooleanState(bool value, string displayText)
    {
        Value = value;
        DisplayText = displayText;
    }
}
```

Then registering the service with the DI as a singleton.